# Laravel Eloquent Nested Condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a small question about nested wheres when using Eloquent in Laravel.
So this is the code I have right now:

```
    $journeys = Journey::with(array('user', 'photo' => function($query){
        $query->where('thumb', '=', '1');
    }))->where('display', '=', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(4)->get();
```

With this I can loop the journeys, even when the nested condition is not met and the photo does not show up because there is no thumb.

I only want to show journeys with photos where thumb is 1. Is this possible with Eloquent?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid my answer was wrong. Deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this happen based on a very recent commit by Taylor: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2435#issuecomment-27525982

If you create a new relationship called `withThumbs` for example you can apply constraints to the relationship to load only the desired journeys:

```
public function withThumbs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Photo')->whereThumb("1");
}
```

This should only load the journeys you're after.